# What criteria does Server Admin check to determine whether a Mac is running OS X Server or not?

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server

In Server Admin, if you try to connect to a Mac which is not a server, you get the message "There is no server available at the address you entered"

Which specific setting(s), file(s), running service(s), are checked to determine whether a Mac is running server or client?

Comment: in case Amit Singh is in the house ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an automagic service called ‘servermgrd’ that listens on tcp port 311.  This is the server daemon for ServerAdmin and ServerMonitor, probably the other tools as well.  I have just checked on a client machine, and the binary does not exist.

Incidently, port 626 is used by ‘serialnumberd’ to see if other OSX Servers are using the same serial number in the same broadcast domain.  The ServerAdmin tool likely just uses servermgrd, though it might also use serialnumberd as a check.